# Continuous Mathematical Solving for Accounting with PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So I have the following data in MySQL database

```
id     date      type      source        particulars     amount    user
1      8/23/19   debit     General       load payment    500.00     1
2      8/24/19   credit    Loan          record loan     7,000.00   1
3      8/22/19   debit     General       grocery         800.00     1
4      8/25/19   credit    General       record salary   10,000.00  1
5      8/10/19   credit    General       other income    20,000.00  1
```

With this data, I want to achieve the following:

1. Sort and group the items by day, month and year
2. Filter the data by user
3. Create a balance statement - the logic is when the type is credit, then perform addition, if debit, perform subtraction

I can only perform the first two tasks I have but it seems that I cannot perform mathematical operations continuously.

I want my output to be like this:

```
INCOME STATEMENT

Period covered: August 2019
Name: 1

8/25/19   credit    General       record salary   +10,000.00
8/22/19   debit     General       grocery         -   800.00 
8/23/19   debit     General       load payment    -   500.00
8/24/19   credit    Loan          record loan     + 7,000.00
8/25/19   credit    General       record salary   +10,000.00
                             CASH ON HAND          25,700.00
```

With the if-else condition, I can only achieve this:

```
Period covered: August 2019
Name: 1

8/25/19   credit    General       record salary   +10,000.00
8/22/19   debit     General       grocery         -   800.00 
8/23/19   debit     General       load payment    -   500.00
8/24/19   credit    Loan          record loan     + 7,000.00
8/25/19   credit    General       record salary   +10,000.00
```

Code that I have tried so far.

```
            <table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                 <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>TYPE</th>
                                <th>SOURCE</th>
                                <th>PARTICULARS</th>
                                <th></th>
                                <th>AMOUNT</th>
                            </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                    <?php 
                        $query = $page->query("SELECT * FROM accounting");
                        $query->execute();

                        while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
                        {
                            ?> 
                            <tr>

                                <td><?php echo $row->id; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row->type; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row->source; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row->particulars; ?></td>
                                <td><?php if ($row->type=='debit') { echo '-'; } else { echo '+'; } ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row->amount; ?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php   }
                   ?>
                   </tbody>
                   </table>
CASH ON HAND:
```

I cant echo the sum/difference of the amount column in the Cash on Hand.

Comment: Please share what you have already tried so that we can help debug it.

Comment: edited and added my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could maintain a sum as you process the rows and then output it at the end:

```
$cash_on_hand = 0;
while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
{
    $cash_on_hand += ($row->type == 'debit' ? -1 : 1) * $row->amount;
    >?
    // output each row
<?php
}
echo "<tr><td colspan=\"5\">CASH ON HAND</td><td>$cash_on_hand</td></tr>";
?>
```

Comment: Yes, that's it. Thank you very much.